# Improve search in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I would like to improve research within my `UITableViewController`.
Now i have an `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"the dog is brown",@"the cat is red",@"the mouse is grey"];
```

Now if I write in my `searchbar` for example: "the cat", the table will show "the cat is red" and it is ok.
But if I write: "cat red", the table will be empty.

What can I do to improve this?

so it becomes like making the search now:

```
-(void)loadArray {

  arraySearch = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];
  [arraySearch addObjectsFromArray: array]; 
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

  [arraySearch removeAllObjects];

  for (int z=0; z<[array count]; z++) {

    if ([[array objectAtIndex:z] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location !=NSNotFound) {

        [arraySearch addObject:[array objectAtIndex:z]];
    }

      [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Thanks to all.

**I FOUND the solution and I would like to share it with you**:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

 [arraySearch removeAllObjects];

  NSArray *listItems = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];


NSMutableArray *arrayPredicate = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *str in listItems) {

    if ([str length] > 0) {
        NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains [cd] %@ OR self contains [cd] %@", str, str];
        [arrayPredicate addObject:pred];
    }
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:arrayPredicate];

[arraySearch addObjectsFromArray:[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];


[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [arraySearch removeAllObjects];

    //Break the sentence into words
    NSArray *listItems = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    //Iterate each word and create predicate statement
    NSMutableArray *predicatesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *str in listItems) {
        [predicatesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@",str]];
    }

    //Concatenate predicate statements by conditional OR
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[predicatesArray componentsJoinedByString:@" OR "]];

    //Filter the array against matching predicate
    [arraySearch addObjectsFromArray:[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I get an error: "too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2" on [array addObject:@"SELF like[c] %@,str];"

Comment: error with: arraySearch = [arraySearch filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];  incompatible pointer types assigning to "NSMutableArray" from "NSArray"

Comment: thanks for your time, but the app crash without log... maybe I'm missing something, but with this code when I add the array to arraysearch?

Comment: I focused on providing you with the logic, seems you need help with syntax. :)) I've edited the answer again.

Comment: you're right, now the app crash with this log: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0xcc0ee50> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key g.'    //g is the letter that I included in the searchbar